# ¿Cómo hago para que un botón en Python solo funcione mientras esté pulsado?

Tags: python, tkinter

Lo que pasa es que estoy realizando una interfaz grafica en Python con Tkinter de un inicio de sesión, donde se pone usuario y contraseña y lo que quiero es que al pulsar un botón se visibilice la contraseña como en facebook y similares, ya que por defecto se ponen "*" lo normal, quiero que se vea la contraseña mientras el usuario mantenga pulsado el botón del ojo y me estoy frustrando ya que intentado muchas cosas y eh buscado por internet y no encuentro algo relacionado

Adjunto mi Código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.font import BOLD
def VerPass():
 EntryPass.config(show="")
Raiz1=Tk()
Eleccion=IntVar()
Contra=StringVar()
Raiz1.title("Sistema de Eventos")
Raiz1.geometry("400x300")
Label(Raiz1, text="Bienvenido a nuestro Sistema de Eventos", font=BOLD, pady=10).pack()
Label(Raiz1, text="Por favor Inicie sesion", font=BOLD, pady=10).pack()
FrameLogin=Frame()
FrameLogin.pack()
Agente=Radiobutton(FrameLogin, text="Agente", value=1, variable=Eleccion, pady=10, padx=10)
Agente.grid(row=0, column=1)
Modelo=Radiobutton(FrameLogin, text="Modelo", value=2, variable=Eleccion, pady=10, padx=10)
Modelo.grid(row=0, column=2)
LabelUsuario=Label(FrameLogin, text="Usuario:", pady=10)
LabelUsuario.grid(row=1, column=1)
EntryUsuario=Entry(FrameLogin)
EntryUsuario.grid(row=1, column=2)
LabelPass=Label(FrameLogin, text="Contraseña:", pady=10)
LabelPass.grid(row=2, column=1)
EntryPass=Entry(FrameLogin)
EntryPass.grid(row=2, column=2)
EntryPass.config(show="*")
BotonLogin=Button(FrameLogin, text="Iniciar Sesion")
BotonLogin.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
BotonRegist=Button(FrameLogin, text="Registrarse")
BotonRegist.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=10, padx=10)
BotonRecup=Button(Raiz1, text="Olvide mi contraseña")
BotonRecup.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
BotonVer=Button(FrameLogin, text="", command=VerPass)
BotonVer.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=10)
Raiz1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Retomando su pregunta, la solución es simple, cuando se vaya a ejecutar el evento del botón de mostrar caracteres, el evento se efectúa por medio de condicional, cuando se muestren los caracteres todo el texto ingresado se reemplazará con los caracteres o `show` en este caso, de igual manera sucede cuando usted los quiere mostrar, se quitaran los caracteres y se mostrará el texto original ingresado en el cuadro de de entrada o el `Entry`.

Esta es la solución frente a su pregunta:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.font import BOLD

def VerPass(): # Aquí es agragar condicional con relación al evento ejecutado, si el cuadro de entrada muestra carácteres (*), todos lo carácteres insertados mostrarán ese carácter, si no, se mostranán los carácteres sin nada.
    if EntryPass.cget('show') == '': # Retomar el parametro 'show' del Entry.
        EntryPass.config(show='*')
        BotonVer.config(text='Mostrar contraseña')
    else:
        EntryPass.config(show='')
        BotonVer.config(text='Ocultar contraseña')

Raiz1=Tk()
Eleccion=IntVar()
Contra=StringVar()

Raiz1.title("Sistema de Eventos")
Raiz1.geometry("400x300")

Label(Raiz1, text="Bienvenido a nuestro Sistema de Eventos", font=BOLD, pady=10).pack()
Label(Raiz1, text="Por favor Inicie sesion", font=BOLD, pady=10).pack()

FrameLogin=Frame()
FrameLogin.pack()

Agente=Radiobutton(FrameLogin, text="Agente", value=1, variable=Eleccion, pady=10, padx=10)
Agente.grid(row=0, column=1)

Modelo=Radiobutton(FrameLogin, text="Modelo", value=2, variable=Eleccion, pady=10, padx=10)
Modelo.grid(row=0, column=2)

LabelUsuario=Label(FrameLogin, text="Usuario:", pady=10)
LabelUsuario.grid(row=1, column=1)

EntryUsuario=Entry(FrameLogin)
EntryUsuario.grid(row=1, column=2)

LabelPass=Label(FrameLogin, text="Contraseña:", pady=10)
LabelPass.grid(row=2, column=1)

EntryPass=Entry(FrameLogin)
EntryPass.grid(row=2, column=2)
EntryPass.config(show="*")

BotonLogin=Button(FrameLogin, text="Iniciar Sesion")
BotonLogin.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

BotonRegist=Button(FrameLogin, text="Registrarse")
BotonRegist.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=10, padx=10)

BotonRecup=Button(Raiz1, text="Olvide mi contraseña")
BotonRecup.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

BotonVer=Button(FrameLogin, text="Mostrar contraseña", command=VerPass)
BotonVer.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=10)

Raiz1.mainloop()
```

> Caracter U+1f441 en este caso es el ojo de ver contraseña, por tanto excede el rango de caracteres preasignado y soportado por el lenguaje Tcl, en este caso use iconos en vez de caracteres en los botones esto ocasiona fallas al ejecutar el script o elimine los caracteres adicionales del rango de caracteres.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me ah funcionado, soy algo principiante con Python, tendré en cuenta lo del carácter del ojo